# How to create an entry with PHP in Wordpress Gravity Forms

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

There is a form on a site that I am working on which I would like to be able to submit entries for from the back-end with PHP. The gravity forms mysql tables should be updated exactly the same way as if a user submitted an entry from the HTML form.
Does Gravity forms provide a class to do this?

Comment: This question makes no sense. You have a form on the back end written in PHP...Okay, that produces HTML to create the form. But you need the gforms mysql tables to be updated as if they submit the entry form? Are you saying that you have a custom form that you want to use outside of gravity forms that still updates gravity forms tables?

Comment: no the form is a gravity form but instead of having the user fill out the form and submit it I want to do this from php as if the user submitted it himself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. The [Gravity Forms API](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gravity_Forms_API) is your friend here, and you'll want to use the [add_entry](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/API_Functions#add_entry) function.